# How can I get my Xbox 1 remote to work with 19.10?

Tags: 19.10, xbox-one

I have recently gotten an Xbox remote to work on a Raspian using `xboxdrv`, but when I try to activate it on Ubuntu, I get an error message that says:

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file xboxdrv does not exist.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The package `xboxdrv` is available in the `Universe` repository. You can find it by searching [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/xboxdrv).

There is no need to add a PPA, [nor should you add a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for) when software is available in Ubuntu repositories.  To install this package, simply open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xboxdrv
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to write an systemd.service by your own.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/xboxdrv.service
```

following content.

```
[Unit]
Description=Xbox controller driver daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
PIDFile=/var/run/xboxdrv.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xboxdrv --daemon --detach --pid-file /var/run/xboxdrv.pid --dbus disabled --silent --mimic-xpad

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you can enable the service.

```
sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/akatch/cdb707856d467bd7cacd)

Answer (score -1):

You have to install xbox driver for linux called xboxdrv. Info: https://xboxdrv.gitlab.io/

<strike>Try:</strike>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grumbel/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
```

Comment: It says no when I go to add the repository
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/603796117255225366/687464560097361966/unknown.png

Comment: this PPA is not maintained, and the software is available in Universe

Comment: Edit: the above repo in not maintained like @Nmath said.